# Cannot re-enable Cloud Functions for Firebase in dialogflow

Tags: google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am working in a dialogflow agent and I had Cloud Functions for Firebase enabled and handling my my intents previously. I disabled them on this agent because I was unable to enable them on another agent and I wanted to see if it was a permission issue or something differing between agents. Now, once disabling Cloud Functions on the previously working agent I cannot re-enable Cloud Functions on that agent so I am locked out of doing any sort work fulfilled by Cloud Functions.

In the console I am flipping the switch from DISABLED to ENABLED and the UI changes showing that it should be enabled. Like this:

[image: after toggling to enabled]

I notice here that there is no Save or Deploy button. Not sure if that is an issue, but when I click on Intents in the side bar and then click back on Fulfillment the screen looks like this again where Cloud Functions are disabled:

[image: fulfillment after going back]

The fact that I am unable to enable Cloud Functions is further confirmed by the fact that the last logs I had in Cloud Functions is from a few days ago when I made the mistake of disabling Cloud Functions fulfillment.

I hope I'm missing something simple here, but I can't find anything (yet) in the dialogflow documentation that tells of anything that I'm missing. I'm kind of at a loss since it was working before and now I can't seem to turn it back on.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run the cloud function after getting edited from the inline editor, you have to give your firebase function link to webhook.

Enable webhook service there and give the link of your cloud function and it will work as you expected.

Comment: The question wants the reverse of this answer: to use the inline editor, instead of using the firebase webhook. I see that this answer might want to help, at least, the user to re-enable the firebase webhook. Nonetheless this answer should not stay at the top, if I may suggest, because more and more users might fall into this "trap", loosing the fastness of building directly into the inline editor, without being able to come back, as the absence of solutions now indicates.

Answer (score 4):

You should navigate to your [firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com), choose the project, click on the left menu on develop > functions, then on the three dots on the right you can delete your function.

You then, go back to your [Dialogflow console](https://console.dialogflow.com/) and select the inline editor toggle, in case it does not work right away, try refreshing the page.

Comment: Yes that is correct, i did it and it deployed the code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That error message seems related to a Dialogflow's limitation in fulfillment. Once you modify your code outside the Inline Editor, you cannot go back to use it, so you have to use your code editor from now on and deploy your functions using Firebase CLI. You can check all the limitations [here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment#limitations).

Comment: Yeah, I'm not trying to update the code in the webpage. I just want to use cloud functions and edit in an external editor. I'm not worried about the red message there. That's fine. Just wanting that switch to stay enabled and cloud functions to actually get run.

Comment: I think you cannot reenable the inline editor because of the limitation I mentioned. Try what Nikhil said to configure your agent's fulfillment.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as I myself also lost my ability to use the fast dialogflow inline editor,

"If you modify your function outside of inline code editor, you can no longer use the editor to modify your Cloud Function for Firebase. Your function will continue to provide fulfillment for your agent, but if you need to make changes, you will need to do so in the Firebase console."

As of today this is a known limitation of dialogflow (see Dialog Flow Fulfillment [Limitations](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment/configure#limitations))

Comment: If you are unable to create a fresh new dialogflow project in order to use only the inline editor, there is an ugly, but still attractive, workaround: you can create or find an unused dialogflow project. You can use the code from your main project inside that unused dialogflow account inline editor, for fast debugging purposes. Every time your experiment passes, you can copy this tested code into your main project's webhook to be (slowly) deployed. It is indeed an ugly setup. But fast, again. Only an idea for now.